# Terraform is trying to recreate a resource

Tags: terraform

Using v0.11.5, not sure why terraform is trying to recreate the lambda function?

```
[1m[31mError: [0m[0m[1mError applying plan:

1 error(s) occurred:

* module.resources.aws_lambda_function.slack-notification-lambda: 1 error(s) occurred:

* aws_lambda_function.slack-notification-lambda: Error creating Lambda function: ResourceConflictException: Function already exist: slack-notification-lambda
    status code: 409, request id: ab39666a-3f4c-11e8-a5b3-3d17af679eea
```

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like the lambda function exists but it isn't stored in your terraform state. 
This can sometimes happen if the state gets interrupted and didn't complete successful.

You can [import](https://www.terraform.io/docs/import/index.html) the resource

### Example

```
terraform import aws_lambda_function.slack-notification-lambda slack-notification-lambda
```

Comment: Thanks! I did a terraform state list and the lambda module was not in the state file. This is being deployed via jenkins pipeline, so now I have to figure out where the disconnect with jenkins and terraform are

Answer (score 0):

I am facing a similar issue in my code pipeline and I was able to fix it by adding terraform backend to store remote state for reach env.

I hope it helps.